# Применение JSTL

Tags: jsp, servlet, jstl

Я учусь, и мне в моей форме входа и регистрации надо применить jstl библиотеку. У меня простая форма для регистрации и входа, приём данных с которых происходит в сервлете. Там же происходит проверка, как отработала прослойка DAO, которая работает с базой данных. Прочитал про теги jstl, и к сожалению не понял как их тут применить.

**main.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="##ffff00">
<form method="Get" action="MainServlet">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>Добро пожаловать на концерт по заявкам</h1>
        <br>
        Логин:<label>
        <input type="text" name="login">
    </label>
        Пароль:<label>
        <input type="password" name="pass">
    </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Войти">
        <br>
        <h2><a href="http://localhost:8080/WebConcertByRequest/registration.jsp">Регистрация</a></h2>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

И такова же рода регистрации.

И ещё такой вопрос. Вот мой сервлет, в котором я разместил проверку if..else. В jstl есть if и when, но без скриплета я не смогу разместить этот оператор в jsp?

```
import concertbyrequest.MySqlUserDao;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(name = "MainServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MainServlet"})
public class MainServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    private String login;
    private String pass;
    private String url_back = "<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2><br><a href='javascript:history.back();'>Назад</a></h2></div>";

    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        login = request.getParameter("login");
        pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if (name.equals("") || login.equals("") || pass.equals("")) {
            out.println("<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2>Вы не заполнили все поля.</h2></div>");
            out.println(url_back);
        } else {
            MySqlUserDao mud = new MySqlUserDao();
            if (!mud.add(name, login, pass)) {
                out.println("<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2>Пользователь " + login + " уже существует.</h2></div>");
                out.println(url_back);
                request.setAttribute("no",1);
            } else {
                out.println("<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2>Пользователь " + login + " успешно зарегестрирован.</h2></div>");
                out.println(url_back);
            }
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/registration.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }

    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        login = request.getParameter("login");
        pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        MySqlUserDao mud = new MySqlUserDao();
        if (mud.getUser(login, pass) != null) {
            out.println("<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2>Добро пожаловать," + login + "</h2></div>");
            out.println(url_back);
        } else {
            out.println("<div style=\"text-align: center;\"><h2>Пользователь " + login + " не зарегестрирован, либо введён неправильный логин или пароль</h2></div>");
            out.println(url_back);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать тег `c:url` в атрибуте `href`. Будет выглядеть вот так:

```
<a href = "<c:url value="/WebConcertByRequest/registration.jsp"/>">Регистрация</a>
```